# Unwanted spaces between li

Tags: html, css, html-lists, space

I'm trying to separate li-items by adding a border-bottom to them.
However, there are unwanted spaces appearing:

[image]

Chrome tells me there is no padding/margin:

[image]

Does anyone know where these spaces come from?

Code:

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;">
  <% 15.times do |whatever| %>
    <li style="border-bottom: 1px solid red;">
       <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
      </div>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you provide the full code so we can reproduce it?

Comment: Is your browser zoomed in?

Comment: @Huelfe I copied the code above into an empty html file (copy&paste the li-tag manually about 10 times) and got the same result so it doesn't seem like my other code is influencing this problem.

Comment: @ovokuro Ok, this confuses me. If I zoom out OR in a little, the whitespace disappears.

Comment: Same here. it seems to depend on the zoom. I tried changing height to ems and it worked better when zoomed but problem is still there near 100%. And no problem in firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing a problem with pixel rounding.

You can add the border to `div` instead, which appears to allow zooming without artefacts.

```css
li div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;">
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: green; display: block; ">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove Height on your inline-style div

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;">
  <% 15.times do |whatever| %>
    <li style="border-bottom: 1px solid red;">
       <div style="width: 100%; background-color: green; display: block; ">
      </div>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I only added the height for visibility purposes. I tried removing it, but the whitespace still appears.

Answer (score 0):

try applying `width:100%; float:left;` to the `<LI>` and/or `<div>`

I am adding a sample here. Please check it.

```css
ul li{
        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul li div{
        width: 100%; 
        height: 40px;
        background-color: green; 
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
       <div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Only works when zooming in. The solution of ovokuro seems to be working though